# Problems with Visual Studio Code C# Debugging

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-code

I am using VS Code to work on a small console application on C# and I cannot use the Debugging Tool (even with the SDK and the C# Extension installed on my PC).

When I run `dotnet run` on terminal It works, but when I try to debug some part of the code I get:

[image]

I believe that is some problem with the launch.json and the tasks.json files but I don't know what to do.

I have also looked at https://74th.github.io/vscode-debug-specs/csharp/ but the problem remains.

Comment: You need to put all your [config into the question](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) and show us a [mcve]

Comment: Honestly use something better than VS Code. Rider is available as community version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to thank [user14492](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3657151/user14492) for the advice, now I am using Visual Studio (not VS Code) at my project and the debug tool works very well.

This [Liam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/542251/liam) looks unkind, if you found the gif annoying just ignore, don't be a jerk.

Answer (score -1):

tasks.json

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "type": "process",
            "args": [
                "build",
                "${workspaceFolder}/ConsoleApplicationDemo.csproj",
                "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
                "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        },
        {
            "label": "publish",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "type": "process",
            "args": [
                "publish",
                "${workspaceFolder}/ConsoleApplicationDemo.csproj",
                "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
                "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        },
        {
            "label": "watch",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "type": "process",
            "args": [
                "watch",
                "run",
                "${workspaceFolder}/ConsoleApplicationDemo.csproj",
                "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
                "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        }
    ]
}
```

launch.json

```
{
   // Use IntelliSense to find out which attributes exist for C# debugging
   // Use hover for the description of the existing attributes
   // For further information visit https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/blob/master/debugger-launchjson.md
   "version": "0.2.0",
   "configurations": [
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Launch (console)",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            // If you have changed target frameworks, make sure to update the program path.
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.1/ConsoleApplicationDemo.dll",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            // For more information about the 'console' field, see https://aka.ms/VSCode-CS-LaunchJson-Console
            "console": "internalConsole",
            "stopAtEntry": false
        },
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Attach",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "attach",
            "processId": "${command:pickProcess}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Refer below URL: https://medium.com/edgefund/c-development-with-visual-studio-code-b860cc71a5ec